# Why isnt the less than operator being called when I insert into a map c++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, operators, overloading

```
class Board {
public:

  virtual void init() = 0;
  virtual void print_board() const = 0;
  virtual Board* clone() const = 0;
  virtual bool less_than(const Board& b2) const = 0;
  inline friend bool operator< (const Board& b1, const Board& b2);
};

inline bool operator< (const Board& b1, const Board& b2){
  std::cout<<"TEST1"<<std::endl;
  return b1.less_than(b2);
}
```

Test1 isn't being printed at all when I insert using mymap[board] = evaluate;
The map is `map<Board*, int>`.

Comment: Can you provide the exact code which you use to test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's calling `operator<(Board*, Board*)`, which just compares the pointers. Either construct your map as `map<Board, Board>` - or create a functor for comparing two map pointers and use it as a template parameter:

```
struct compareBoards {
    bool operator()(Board const * b1, Board const * b2) const {
        return *b1 < *b2; }
}
```

And

```
map<Board*, int, compareBoards> boardMap;
```

Comment: How would I use it as template parameter if my map is a private member of a different class?